# check wheather gps is available or not in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager

hi i am making an app based on gps... i have tested it and working fine in iphone simulator 3.0..

but when gps is not available i want to generate an alert...(i just remove the internet connection)
i used following method but did not work....

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error getting Current Location" message:@"Please check your Internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];

}
```

so please tell me how to do that
(currently working iphone 3.0)

and please also tell if i shift this app.to iphone 4 will it work...asking because i have listen that iphone 4 has gps problem... for this i tried this on simulator 4.0...but it failed...

Comment: CoreLocation != GPS. There are other ways that iOS devices can find their location. You should review the documentation, sample code and video presentations for CoreLocation available on Apple's site. Additionally, saying something "failed" in a question is nearly useless without details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPS on the iphone, or any device for that matter, does not depend having an internet connection.

Comment: Well you'll need to reframe your question. The title seemed reasonably obvious "check wheather gps is available or not in iphone". The GPS is always "available" if the device has GPS, whether or not it's accurate is another question.

Comment: He means how to check a device has GPS or Not.?